# C++ Read input in any order

Tags: c++

I am trying to store user input into respective variable types.
The order in which the user inputs can be any.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double i;
    char x;
    cin >> i;
    cin >> x; // This only works if the double is read first

    cout << i << x << endl;
}
```

How can I store the input into their respective variable?

Comment: This is impossible - how would you tell the difference between the character '2' and the number 2?

Answer (score 2):

Because the input is a character string, whatever the user inputs can be put inside a string. As such, you can use the following naïve algorithm:

- Read the input into a string.
- If the input represents a number, then extract if from the string and store it in `x`.
- Otherwise, if the input is a single character, then extract if from the string and store it in `i`.

A more general approach that is much more complex is to implement a parser. There is no standard way to implement a parser in C++.

> ok but how do you extract the numbers

You can use a string stream for example.

Comment: ok but how do you extract the numbers. I can extract the chars using a for loop but i dont know how to do it for numbers